# Application is loading only one (default) controller in php mvc project?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I am building custom mvc framework from scratch and when I put something something to print in my PageController, application is working, but when I create some other controller and try to print something, it just prints data from PageController.

I think that the problem is on where I put variable   protected `$currentController = 'PageController';`   and   `$this->currentController = new PageController();`.

Now I tried putting `$this->currentController = new $this->currentController;` and I get this error:

> 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PageController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\App\Libraries\Core.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\public\index.php(7): App\Libraries\Core->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\App\Libraries\Core.php on line 20 '.

Also I'm using composer and autoloading with psr-4 and namespacing.

Core.php

```
namespace App\Libraries;

use App\Controllers\PageController;

class Core
{
   protected $currentController = 'PageController';
   protected $currentMethod = 'index';
   protected $params = [];

   public function __construct()
   {
      $url = $this->getUrl();
      if (file_exists('../App/Controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]) . '.php')) {
        $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
        unset($url[0]);
      }
      require_once '../App/Controllers/' . $this->currentController . '.php';
      $this->currentController = new PageController();
   }

   public function getUrl()
   {
      if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        return $url;
      }
   }
}
```

PageController.php

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class PageController
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      echo "Page Loaded!!!";
   }
}
```

PostController.php

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class PostController
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      echo "Post Controller Loaded!!!";
   }
}
```

index.php (in public folder)

```
use App\Libraries\Core;

require_once '../App/bootstrap.php';

$init = new Core;
```

bootstrap.php (in App folder)

```
<?php

require dirname(__DIR__) . '..\vendor\autoload.php';
```

I expect when I make some other controller to be able to write something in it and get output without errors or the same data as in PageController.

Comment: @tereško I'm trying to write it by myself. Besides, it's a bit advanced for my current level.

Comment: @DanielFoust How should I procede if I don't use require_once statement, in order to dynamically call controller?

Comment: @DanielFoust I did all that, and I'm having trouble with dynamically calling $namespace_path. I don;t know what to put in that variable so I don't get errors like 'Class name must be a valid object or a string' or similar.

Comment: https://github.com/gacho10/php  here it is. this is where it works for PageController just without $namespace_path logic.

Comment: @DanielFoust Did that, it works almost like before, except now when I enter posts in url to get data from posts controller I get 'Object 404 not found' where as before I got the same data as in PageController. Also when I try to change $this->currentController = new \App\Controllers\PageController; with $this->currentController = new $this->currentController; I get PageController not found! error. I really don't know what to do. Here is git for that code  https://github.com/gacho10/gacho. And sorry and thank you for your trouble :)

Comment: There were a few things I had to change.  Make sure that your `rewritebase` in your htaccess goes from the correct document root.  If you're not using virtual hosts, then you need to use the path from the localhost to the project.  Also, you are still using a `require` statement before calling the object.  You do not need that.  Remove it.  At the top, add the namespace to the currentController property.  If `$url[0]` is set, prefix the namespace like this: `$this->currentController = '\App\Controllers\\' . ucwords($url[0]);` .  That got the posts controller and page controllers working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled your repository down and there were a few things I had to change.

Make sure that your `RewriteBase` in your `.htaccess` goes from the correct document root. If you're not using virtual hosts, then you need to use the path from the localhost to the project.

Also, you are still using a require statement before calling the object. You do not need that. Remove it.

At the top, add the namespace to the `$currentController` property. If `$url[0]` is set, prefix the namespace like this:

```
$this->currentController = '\App\Controllers\\' . ucwords($url[0]);
```

That got the posts controller and page controllers working.